# AttributeError in python/numpy when constructing function for certain values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm writing Python code to generate and plot 'super-Gaussian' functions, as:

```
def supergaussian(x, A, mu, sigma, offset, N=8):
    """Supergaussian function, amplitude A, centroid mu, st dev sigma, exponent N, with constant offset"""
    return A * (1/(2**(1+1/N)*sigma*2*scipy.special.gamma(1+1/N))) * numpy.exp(-numpy.absolute(numpy.power(x-mu,N))/(2*sigma**N)) + offset

init_x = numpy.arange(-100,100,1.0)
init_y = supergaussian(init_x, 1, 0, 25, 0, N=12)
```

Following code just makes a plot of it. For a reason I cannot fathom, this code works fine when using the default value of 8 for `N`, or for values of `N` up to 13. When `N` is 14 or higher, the function crashes with an error message:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

At the return line in the function definition. Any ideas? Since the only thing in that line that use .exp is the `numpy.exp` the error message seems to imply that `numpy` is being interpreted as a float, but only for large values of `N`...

I'm running python 3.3.2 with numpy 1.7.1 and scipy 0.12.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error is due to some numpy dtype weirdness.  I'm not sure exactly how it works internally, but for some reason `2*25**14` triggers a change in how Numpy handles the datatypes:

```
>>> type(np.max(-numpy.absolute(numpy.power(init_x-0,13)))/(2*25**13))
<type 'numpy.float64'>
>>> type(np.max(-numpy.absolute(numpy.power(init_x-0,14)))/(2*25**14))
<type 'float'>
```

With 13, it still uses Numpy's float64 type, but with 14 it somehow reverts back to regular float.  This is why you get the AttributeError: a normal Python float doesn't have the `exp` method, which is a numpy ufunc method.  (The error is not due to the name `numpy` being interpreted as a float.  Sometimes these numpy-internal errors are unhelpful in that they don't tell you what the object is that doesn't have the attribute.)

However, this is only happening because the number `2*25**N` is a regular Python long, not a value of a numpy datatype.  You can fix it by pre-wrapping that value in a numpy dtype, like this:

```
def supergaussian(x, A, mu, sigma, offset, N=8):
    """Supergaussian function, amplitude A, centroid mu, st dev sigma, exponent N, with constant offset"""
    denom = np.float64(2*sigma**N)
    return A * (1/(2**(1+1/N)*sigma*2*scipy.special.gamma(1+1/N))) * numpy.exp(-numpy.absolute(numpy.power(x-mu,N))/denom) + offset
```

Now it works fine for large values.

The conversion failure appears to be due to the fact that `2*25**14` is too big to fit in a numpy int64.  This looks like a bug to me: if it's too big for int64, it should fall back to float64 or raise an error, not silently fall back to plain float.  It looks like there is a related bug on the [numpy tracker](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3409), but that looks slightly different.  You might want to raise the issue on the numpy tracker and/or mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what's happening. I'll submit to the numpy tracker.