# AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to utilize the scipy.stats.linregress() function. I double checked that both my inputs are the same size and both are arrays. However I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chianh/Desktop/Reliability Py Scripts/MedianRanks_Solver_Rev0.py", line 48, in <module>
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(data, median_rank)
  File "C:\Users\chianh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_mstats_common.py", line 81, in linregress
    r_den = np.sqrt(ssxm * ssym)
AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

The code that i wrote is pasted below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import scipy.stats as stats
from sympy import Symbol, binomial, expand_func, solve, solveset

def eval_median_rank( mylist ):
    P = 0.5                         # Percentage Point (would be 0.5 to be median)
    Z = Symbol('Z', real=True)      # Median Rank (Should be solved for each test unit)
    result = []                     # Place holder for the evaluated Median Ranks

    # Re-iterate and perform for each data point
    for j in range(1, mylist.size+1):
        eq = 0
        k = j

        # Generate the Median Rank equation which will be solved for 'Z' or Median Rank
        while k <= mylist.size:
            eq = eq + expand_func(binomial(mylist.size, k) * (Z**k) * (1 - Z)**(mylist.size-k))
            k += 1
        eq = eq - P

        # Solve for only Median Rank solutions that only fall between 0 and 1.
        # Then append to the returning list
        sol = [i for i in solve(eq, Z, list=True) if (i > 0) and (i < 1)]
        result.extend(sol)

    result.sort(reverse=True)
    return np.array(result)

######################################################################################################



# Note that the samples must be ordered in ascending fail-time/UOM,
# and the system must be solved in that order.

data = np.array([96, 257, 498, 763, 1051, 1744], dtype=object)
rank = np.arange(1, data.size+1)
median_rank = eval_median_rank(rank)
print(median_rank)

# Use Scipy's stats package to perform Least-Squares fit
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(data, median_rank)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833639/attributeerror-in-python-numpy-when-constructing-function-for-certain-values

Comment: Don't pass sympy objects to scipy functions.  scipy doesn't handle sympy's `Float` object.

Comment: Would it be able to handle numpy arrays?

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser so is the solution just to convert the `sympy` floats to normal `float`s?

Comment: @CharlieParker: Yes, that should work.